# App delegate doesn't work after starting using Storyboards -iOS

Tags: ios, storyboard, appdelegate

I have a small problem with my game.. I wanna stop my game whenever it's interrupted.

My `stopGame` method was working when I called it in `applicationWillResignActive` when I was using xib files. When I changed it to storyboards, it stopped working.. `applicationWillResignActive` still works with storyboards and my `stopGame` method is called, but for some reason, my game does not stop..

Has someone faced a problem like this? And possible solutions please.. 
Thanks in advance..

Some Code

App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication *) application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *) launchOptions
{    
        mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

        [self.window addSubview: mainViewController.view];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        return YES;
}


- (void) applicationWillResignActive: (UIApplication *) application
{    
    [mainViewController stopGame];
}
```

MainViewController

```
- (IBAction) stopGame
{
        self.gameRunning = NO;
        [currentLevel deactivate];
}
```

Level_1

```
- (void) deactivate
{
        [levelTimer invalidate];
        levelTimer = nil;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to post some relevant code.  For example, is this openGL? using a framework?  Do you have UIKit view controllers?  We need more information to help you...

Comment: i have added some code..  No OpenGL. but UIKit with ViewControllers. What sort of info do u need? Thanks..

Comment: Is `currentLevel` non-nil?  Have you stepped into `[currentLevel deactivate]`?  What does it do?  (And if `stopGame` is being called, why do you think it's an app delegate problem?)

Comment: I have pasted the `currentLevel deacticate` method. yes you are right actually. stopGame is called. I have a log message in my `stopGame` method and it keeps printing it when interrupted.. maybe it's not an app delegate problem but I can't find another reason. StopGame still works when used by UIButton..

Comment: when i put xib files back, it works by the way.

Comment: Are you sure that mainViewController is the right viewcontroller, the one that you have on screen? Probably the visible viewcontroller is loaded from storyboard, and mainViewController is another instance that does...nothing :). What happens if you comment all the lines referring to mainViewController ij the applicationDidFinishLaunching method? Is the game still working?

Answer (score 0):

When you use storyboard, the default main entry point of the application is the storyboard, starting from the initial viewController (the one that has an arrow coming from the left margin of the storyboard). At the app launch the initial viewcontroller is unarchived, initialized and its view is added to the main window dinamically. 
So, the code you have in applicationDidFinishLaunching is allocating **another** VC, that is not the same that is loaded by the app. For this reason, you are sending the stopGame message to the wrong VC. 
Delete all your code referring to mainViewController from applicationDidFinishLaunching and applicationWillResignActive then add, in applicationWillResignActive:

```
[(MainViewController *)self.window.rootViewController stopGame];
```

Comment: Yes.. That works well if MainViewController is rootviewController.. However my rootViewController UINavigationController.. I am getting this error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController stopGame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x967c8b0'` How can I fix this??

Comment: [(MainViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController visibleViewController] stopGame];

Comment: Or you should use topViewController instead of visibleViewController if your visible view controller could be another (if it changes during game)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers..  I just don't understand how to use it.. are there any tutorials on this? Let's say I have  RootViewController->AnotherViewController->Navigation Controller->MainViewController, then what should it be? It's very confusing..